# How to know when to stop the location services?

Tags: ios, core-location

to retrieve location of the user when the app is in the background i first do `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` then when `DidUpdateLocations` is fired i do with a second `CLLocationManager` `startUpdatingLocation` to retrieve the exact geoposition (with an accuracy on 100m)

The problem is that the doc say:

> Calling this method causes the location manager to obtain an initial
>   location fix (which may take several seconds). After that, the receiver generates update events primarily when the value in the distanceFilter property is exceeded.

So as i understand the first `DidUpdateLocations` will be called with a fix not really accurate, and with time other `DidUpdateLocations` will be called with more accurate location.

Now the problem is, when (and how?) did i need to stop the startUpdatingLocation ? i m in the background so i can't use any timer or think like this

Answer (score 0):

Since you require a 100m accuracy, you can simply check the location horizontal accuracy property. If the condition is fulfilled you can stop the core location manager otherwise you keep tracking.
Be aware that usually the callback of significant monitoring changes keeps your app alive for a minimum amount of time.

> At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given
>   a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart
>   location services and process the location data. (You must manually
>   restart location services in the background before any pending
>   location updates can be delivered, as described in Knowing When to
>   Start Location Services.) Because your app is in the background, it
>   must do minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as querying the
>   network) that might prevent it from returning before the allocated
>   time expires. If it does not, your app will be terminated. If an iOS
>   app needs more time to process the location data, it can request more
>   background execution time using the
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: method of the
>   UIApplication class.